# Style for custom control not applied

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, custom-controls

I am trying to create (my first) custom control. It contains a few DependencyProperties that are not in the code provided here for the sake of simplicity.

```
public class StatusBlock : Label
{
    static StatusBlock()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(StatusBlock), 
               new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(StatusBlock)));
    }
}
```

Now I want to apply a custom layout and have created the following lines in `Themes/Generic.xaml`. Obviously the layout is just for testing.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:StatusBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Controls:StatusBlock}">
                <Grid Background="Red" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100" >
                    <TextBlock Text="foobar"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

However, it is not applied. It compiles fine, but the style is not applied. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the xaml code which host your custom control

Comment: You mean where I display the control in my window? `<GrassoftUtils:StatusBlock Height="100" Width="300"/>`

Comment: I can't spot any issue with your code  since I was able to see the style in my window which is hosting the custom label with back color &  text.

Comment: I have control/style in one assembly and use it in my actual project as a dll. Will that change anything? I have tried placing the style in the Generic.xaml in my main project, but still nothing.

Comment: As long as you refer the Dll and create a xaml namespace reference as xmlns:Ctl="clr-namespace:CLabelNameSpace;assembly=CLabelAssembly" , it should fine. Just food for thought would be create a custom control with in the same project where it consume. This would give us chance to filter out root causes.

Comment: good point. That works. If I reference the control by the dll it works. The control itself is recognized. But the style is not. Any idea how I can approach that?

Comment: 1) post the xaml of the window where it is suppose to display .
2) do you know how to use snoop ? , observe your control and check
the Style Property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the style itself works (as you mentioned in the comment), the issue is in the relationship of your dll and your project where you want to display the control. Add this to you `AssemblyInfo.cs` of the dll project (it needs `using System.Windows;`):

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
   ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
    //(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
    // or application resource dictionaries)
   ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly //where the generic resource dictionary is located
    //(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
    // app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
)]
```